# Get the get the key of a dictionary value that is saved inside a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

```
import random
from words import word_dict

def get_word():
    word = random.choice(list(word_dict.values()))
    return word.upper()
```

So I am importing this dictionary and getting a random value from it and saving it inside a variable. Now if i want to get the key of that same random value, how would I get the key? Any Help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
val = get_word()
key = next(k for k, v in word_dict.items() if v.upper() == val)
```

There is, of course, no guarantee as to which key you get, as multiple keys might have the same value. If you have to do this reverse lookup repeatedly, you better build an appropriate data structure:

```
rev = {v.upper(): k for k, v in word_dict.items()}

key1 = rev[val1]
key2 = rev[val2]
```

The smartest however would be to get a random key first, and do the lookup later based on the random key.

Comment: So what if i store the key inside the word variable instead of the value and the try to extract the value for that random key. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get the key along with the value when you pick at random:

```
import random
from words import word_dict

def get_word():
    key,word = random.sample(word_dict.items(),1)[0]
    return word.upper(),key
```

*note that I changed `choice()` to `sample()` in order to avoid the creation of a temporary list with all the entries in the dictionary (which I suspect is quite large).*

Comment: Thank you for replying. I saw your code and it gave me something to thing about and with a bit of modification to your code i was able to fix my issue. How ever another issue arises that variable word always chooses the last element in the dictionary. Should i use another data type instead of dictionary? Some ideas please?

Comment: I would need to see how your word_dict is being built.  Are you certain that the values are different for each of these keys?

Comment: Yes sir the values are different. My dictionary looks as such. word_dict = {}
word_dict["Fruit"] = "Apple"
word_dict["Fruit"] = "Orange" word_dict["Food"] = "Cake"
word_dict["Food"] = "Pasta"
word_dict["Food"] = "Pizza" word_dict["Drink"] = "Mohito"
word_dict["Drink"] = "Pepsi"
word_dict["Drink"] = "Coke". There are more values as such but with these keys.